# Read input from chat window

Tags: java, user-interface, input, client-server

So our teacher tried to  help and wrote the GUI for our chat server/client assignment, but I can't figure out how to read the input from the GUI. Whatever I type just sits there until I type something out. I cant figure out how to read it. I have been stuck on this part for the better part of the day and I am giving up.  I will post the classes, and I don't want the answers for questions being asked in the code, I just need to be able to have whatever I type in the text box able to be read! I can figure the rest out! I thought the connection part would be the hardest, I didn't expect input to be a problem :/

Server Class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server
{

private static final int PORT = 8889;
private static ServerSocket server;
public static int connections;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    server = new ServerSocket(PORT);

    System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");

    Socket clientConnection;
    while (true)
    {
        if (connections >=5)
        {
            clientConnection = server.accept();
            System.out.println("No more connections can be made at this time.You will be disconnected.");
            server.close();
        }

        else {
        clientConnection = server.accept();
        //CommandHandler handler = new CommandHandler(clientConnection);
        System.out.println("Client connected.");
        connections += 1;
        System.out.println("There are " + connections + "user(s) at this time");
        //Thread t = new Thread(handler);
        //t.start();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Client Class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChatClient
{
public static final String HOST= "localhost";
public static final int PORT = 8889;

private ChatWindow window;
private Socket connection;


public ChatClient()
{   
    this.window = new ChatWindow(this);

    try {
        Socket serverConnection = null;
        try {
            serverConnection = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
            ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(
                    serverConnection.getInputStream());
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(
                    serverConnection.getOutputStream());

            } finally {
            serverConnection.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}




public void sendMessage(String message)
{   
    //TODO - USE THE OUTPUT STREAM TO WRITE THE MESSAGE TO THE SERVER
    //       THIS METHOD IS INVOKED BY THE window WHEN THE USER ENTERS
    //       TEXT TO SEND TO THE CHAT SERVER


}


private void start()
{           
    //TODO - ADD CODE THAT WILL CONTINUOUSLY READ
            //       MESSAGES FROM THE SERVER  
            //       USE THE window.printMessage() TO DISPLAY
            //       THE MESSAGE IN THE CHAT WINDOW
}   




public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ChatClient chatClient = new ChatClient();
    chatClient.start();

}

}
```

Chat Window Class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ChatWindow extends JFrame
{

private ChatClient client;

private JTextArea messageArea = new JTextArea(10, 32);
private JTextField inputArea = new JTextField(32);

public ChatWindow(ChatClient theClient)
{
    this.client = theClient;

    //when the user closes the window, make sure the user is logged out.
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
        {
            try {
                client.sendMessage("LOGOUT");
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // GUI COMPONENTS ------------------------------------------

    // MESSAGE AREA: All messages from all clients are displayed here
    messageArea.setEditable(false);
    messageArea.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    messageArea.setLineWrap(true);

    // make sure the scroll bar stays are the bottom
    DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) messageArea.getCaret();
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);

    // INPUT AREA: Input area where client enters text message
    // The message is sent when the user presses enter
    inputArea.addActionListener(new InputAreaActionListener());

    Container content = getContentPane();
    content.add(new JScrollPane(messageArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    content.add(inputArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setTitle("Chat Client");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    inputArea.requestFocusInWindow();
    setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * 
 * This method adds the message to the end of the message area followed by a
 * new line character.
 * 
 * @param message
 */
public void printMessage(String message)
{
    messageArea.append(String.format("%s\n", message));
    try
    {
        messageArea.setCaretPosition(messageArea.getLineStartOffset(messageArea.getLineCount() - 1));
    }
    catch (BadLocationException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private class InputAreaActionListener implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();

        // ask the chat client to send the message to the server
        try {
            client.sendMessage(command);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        inputArea.setText("");
        inputArea.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
}

}
```

I have a feeling it is something simple and maybe I am just looking at this too hard or too long. Any help or criticism is gladly received. Any class can be modified EXCEPT for the Chat Window Class :/

Comment: It looks `sendMessage(String message)` in `Client` takes the input as an argument. You shouldn't have to do anything other than figure out how to send `message` to the server.

Comment: So use the output stream to take the input and change it to argument then send to server?

Comment: .....yes, but you're going to need to turn those into member variables for your class. Right now, they get defined as local variables in the constructor, and are destroyed once it finishes.

Comment: See thats what I thought but he set up the starting code in a funny way, this is how he wanted the constructor to be set up.
    //TODO - MAKE A CONNECTION TO THE SERVER.//       ESTABLISH THE INPUT AND OUTPUT STREAMS
  //       NEEDED TO WRITE MESSAGES TO THE SERVER AND
  //       TO READ MESSAGES FROM THE SERVER

Comment: That's exactly what you are doing, just make your local variables into member variables (i.e., move their declaration next to `private JTextField inputArea = new JTextField(32);`).

Comment: Maybe I am not being clear, sorry for the confusion, I cannot touch the Chat Windows class. We aren't allowed to modify it. I originally had the input output streams as member variables in the Chat Client class but the TODO under the Chat Client class's constructor declaration said to "establish the input and output streams needed to write messages and read from server" under its constructor. Hence the confusion, does that make sense or no?

Comment: Not really. I'm not telling you to change `ChatWindows`. I'm telling you to make `reader` and `writer` (the variables you define in `public ChatClient()`) into member variables of the class, like `window` and `connection` are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to implement the sendMessage function, like the TODO message says you can use the class `OutputStream`, that in this case, is the `PrintWriter` instance, like this:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
out.println(message);
```

With this you'll achieve sending the message through the Client.

Comment: Ok I implemented that and now it throws a null pointer exception for Client on line 45. I tried throwing IO Exception and using try catch blocks :/

Comment: Ok, I'd recommend you as well to catch an `UnknownHostException` just in case that the Host can't be recognized, remember that to be able to send a message you can use the `PrintWriter` function `println()`, so you can now have: `writer.println(message);`,  and you can read that from the server using `readLine()`